# alguien sabe porque la Url de un servicio Rest creado en c# viene con wsdl?

Tags: c#

Alguien podría ayudarme diciéndome porque la Url viene de esta forma si es un servicio Rest, http://192.168.15.215/EstacionesRest/svcEstaciones.svc?wsdl

según lo que he leído ese término es de Soap, Pero al ejecutar el servicio se crea pero me manda con eso.Y me dicen que algo estoy haciendo mal pero no se que ni en qué parte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas segura que creaste un servicio REST? como lo creaste? eso parece un webservice...

Comment: si es un wcf rest. configurado con webHttpBinding

Comment: Yo no veo nada malo en el webservice.. Qué es específicamente lo que te está fallando? Tal vez quitandole el '?wsdl' es lo que estas buscando.

Comment: Ahora por otro lado, si no tienes un requerimiento especifico en usar wcf, te recomiendo mejor comiences con Web Api (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/apis)

Comment: exacto la cuestion es que no me debe de aparecer con el wsdl ..porque deja de ser un Rest..eso es de Soap..pero no entiendo bien..soy nueva en esto..

Answer (score 2):

Acaso lo hiciste en WCF? Si es asi, necesitas configurar tu servicio en tu App.Config como en este ejemplo:

```
<system.ServiceModel>  

   <services>  
   <!-- Define the service endpoints. This section is optional in the new  
    default configuration model in .NET Framework 4. -->  
      <service>  
         <endpoint/>  
      </service>  
   </services>  

   <bindings>  
   <!-- Specify one or more of the system-provided binding elements,  
    for example, <basicHttpBinding> -->   
   <!-- Alternatively, <customBinding> elements. -->  
      <binding>  
      <!-- For example, a <BasicHttpBinding> element. -->  
      </binding>  
   </bindings>  

   <behaviors>  
   <!-- One or more of the system-provided or custom behavior elements. -->  
      <behavior>  
      <!-- For example, a <throttling> element. -->  
      </behavior>  
   </behaviors>  

</system.ServiceModel>
```

Comment: si es con wcf.Si configure en web.config .Pero checare con el ejemplo para no tener errores.